# Flutter web app not responding properly from mobile on (desktop mode)

Tags: flutter

The app works perfectly and smoothly from pc browsers, and it is a bit laggy from mobile browsers,
but it is unusable from from mobile browser on (desktop mode) on phones with big screen resolutions.. it doesn't respond to clicks correctly.

my mobile's screen resolution:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGsO0.jpg)

I thought it is a responsivity issue but I fixed that and the problem wasn't solved.

this is the link of my app: https://tree-plan-viewer.web.app/

Comment: try with the other renderer (currently it's html on mobile, so try canvas), maybe you will get different results

Comment: I've checked it with iPhone 12 and iPhone 8 (with safari and google chrome browsers), everything seems to be ok :/ How could I reproduce your bug?

Comment: @mightybruno I rebuilt the app with canvas renderer and it made it less laggy from mobile browsers which is nice :) but the bug of clicking is still there unfortunately

Comment: @Karol I tried a number of mobiles and simulators and the bug appears on some of them (on my phone (Huawei nova 7i) and on pixel 3a simulator).

Comment: @Omar Othman, Which browser do you use? What do you mean by the bug of clicking?

Comment: @Karol I use chrome, the bug is that the whole app is shifted up (it is out of the screen) as a result the app bar is completely hidden.. and the click box of the widgets is still as it is not shifted, so I need to click about 30px below the widget to actually click it.